# Numpy - How generate the following n-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's consider two matrix "A,B" $(2 \times 2)$, how can I get the result "C" below, using numpy?

Here the code for the matrix A and B:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
])

B = np.array([
    [0.5, 0.3],
    [0.1, 0.6],
])

# My desired output: 
C = [
    [
        [1*0.5, 1*0.3],
        [1*0.1, 1*0.6],
    ],
    [
        [2*0.5, 2*0.3],
        [2*0.1, 2*0.6],
    ],
]
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you just write the matrix in code block, with each row on a different line? I think LaTex formatting works for the mathematical stack exchanges; but I don't think they work on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I am going to adjust the question!

Comment: What have you tried so far? If we do your homework for you do we get the credit?

Comment: `np.outer` may be useful, possible with `.reshape`. `np.einsum` can probably get you almost anywhere, once you manage to wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add a new axis](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) to your first array in order to multiply into that axis:

```py
C = A[:, np.newaxis]*B
```